# How to dynamically increase height of ColumnTexts in ITEXT?

Tags: java, height, itext

I am trying to add 2 columnTexts in a document say ct & ct1.

If ct height increases automatically ct1  should adjust accordingly with respect to height.

I tried implementing this way,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        ItextHieghtTest i = new ItextHieghtTest();
        i.setTableHght();
    }

    void setTableHght() throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
        Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.LETTER.rotate();
        float text1_Hieght = 0;

        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("NextLineTextPDF.pdf"));
        doc.setPageSize(pageSize);
        doc.open();

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        float x = 6.47f * 72f;
        float y = pageSize.getHeight() - (1.13f * 72f);

        Font blue = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED),10f,0,Color.BLUE);
        Chunk greenText = new Chunk("22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_2222222222222222222222222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222Text_22222222222222222222", blue);

        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
        ct.setSimpleColumn(x, y, 750, 50);
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
        p2.add(greenText);
        ct.addElement(p2);
        text1_Hieght = ColumnText.getWidth(p2);
        ct.go();

        pageSize = PageSize.LETTER.rotate();
        float y1  = pageSize.getHeight() - (text1_Hieght/100+ 2.000f * 72f);
        if(text1_Hieght >750 && text1_Hieght <1450)
            y1 = pageSize.getHeight() - (text1_Hieght/100+ 2.222f * 72f);
        if(text1_Hieght >1450 && text1_Hieght <1750)
            y1 = pageSize.getHeight() - (text1_Hieght/100 + 2.444f * 72f);
        if(text1_Hieght >1750 && text1_Hieght <2050)
            y1 = pageSize.getHeight() - (text1_Hieght/100 + 2.666f * 72f);
        if(text1_Hieght >2050 && text1_Hieght <2350)
            y1 = pageSize.getHeight() - (text1_Hieght/100 + 2.888f * 72f);
        if(text1_Hieght >2350 && text1_Hieght <2550)
            y1 = pageSize.getHeight() - (text1_Hieght/100 + 3.000f * 72f);
        System.out.println("text1_Hieght " + text1_Hieght + "&" + y1) ;

        PdfContentByte cb1 = writer.getDirectContent();
        ColumnText ct1 = new ColumnText(cb1);
        ct1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        ct1.setSimpleColumn(x, 1f * 7, 10.5f * 72f, y1);
        ct1.setYLine(y1);
        ct1.addElement(new Chunk("text_3333333333333333333333333333333"));
        ct1.go();

        doc.close();
    }
```

But the problem is, if text1_Hieght >2350 , my ct1 height is not auto adjusting and it is been over written by ct.

Can some one help me in dynamically adjusting ct1 automatically if ct height increases?

Thanks

Comment: If you were able to execute your code, then you were using an obsolete version of iText. I have removed 4 lines from your code sample that without any doubt create a PDF that is in violation with ISO-32000-1.

Comment: You are defining a leading and an alignment for the `ColumnText`, yet you use `ColumnText` in **composite mode**. Obviously, the leading and alignment will be ignored. I'll remove them from your code sample.

Comment: When using `ColumnText`, you are take charge of defining all coordinates. There is no such thing as "auto-adjusting". You need to do all the Math yourself. I have edited your code, removing some things that didn't make sense. Unfortunately, I have no clue what it is that you're trying to achieve. Maybe you should make a drawing.

Comment: I don't understand why you need all the `if` statements for. Are you sure you don't want to do `float y1 = ct.getYLine();` IMHO, the variable `text1_Hieght` doesn't make any sense. (By the way: it's height, not hieght.)

Comment: `pageSize.getHeight() - (text1_Hieght...)` how is this not driving you crazy??